# upgrade of cordova 1.8.1 to cordova 3.6.3 causing issues

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have a sample app and I upgraded cordova library of the app from 1.8.1 to 3.6.3 and now when I click signout from the app, it doesn't do anything. Here is what I found from the log when clicked on "Signout"

Log for 3.6.3

```
10-02 10:39:39.897: D/com.abc.company.net.DefaultHttpConnect(622): (POST Url)https://cola.myserver.com:9486/sso/SSOServlet
10-02 10:39:39.977: D/CordovaActivity(622): Paused the application!
10-02 10:39:39.977: D/CordovaWebView(622): Handle the pause
10-02 10:39:39.977: D/CordovaActivity(622): Resuming the App
10-02 10:39:50.707: W/IdleConnectionHandler(622): Removing a connection that never existed!
```

And this is what I found from Log for 1.8.1

```
10-02 10:12:38.002: D/com.abc.company.net.DefaultHttpConnect(622): (POST Url)https://cola.myserver.com:9486/sso/SSOServlet
10-02 10:12:38.042: D/DroidGap(622): DroidGap.startActivityForResult(intent,-1)
10-02 10:12:38.112: D/DroidGap(622): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
```

Doesn't anyone know why it is not calling `startActivityForResult` in cordova3.6.3 Or am I missing anything in my library?

Comment: Cordova/Phonegap has been overhauled several times since 1.8, so I don't think one can rely on DroidGap methods still being around.

Comment: That is true. My second log is when I was using Cordova1.8.1 library, that's why it shows DroidGap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by removing the line `android:launchMode="singleTop"` from android manifest file. What is launchMode and how it should be used? More explanation here http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode